# Intercepting File Writes on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, file-io

I have a program that generates information from the contents of files, however, I believe it would be more efficient if I were able to do this as the files are being written; rather than having to then read the contents back after some delay, since I can simply generate the data as the file is writing to disk.

What method(s) are available for an application to hook into the file-write process, i.e- to process the data stream as it's being written to disk? Also, which of these (if any) are allowable for app store apps?

I've been considering using a Spotlight Importer, however this still involves reading the contents of a file after they've been written, in which case I'm relying on the file still being in the RAM cache to reduce disk access.

Comment: I'm not necessarily talking about intercepting all file writes; more like registering my app (or a plugin) as interested in file writes to suitable locations, so the OS can pass those write operations through my program before they hit the reach the file-system. I'm not transforming them, just reading as they're written so I can generate the data I want to store elsewhere.

Comment: Again, I'm not talking about circumventing permissions; I'm talking about reading the contents of a file as they're being written, rather than having to read them afterwards. I'm not talking about files I don't have permission to access, it's purely an issue of performance. if you're the one that's rated to close this issue then you're being paranoid about a non-security related problem.